# pthreads and drand48 concurrency performance

Tags: c, pthreads

According to specification, the function rand() in C uses mutexes to lock context (http://sourcecodebrowser.com/uclibc/0.9.27/rand_8c.html). So if I use multiple threads that call it, my program will be slow because all threads will try to access this lock region.

So, I have found drand48(), another random number generator function, which does not have locks (http://sourcecodebrowser.com/uclibc/0.9.27/drand48_8c.html#af9329f9acef07ca14ea2256191c3ce74). But, somehow, my parallel program is still slower than the serial one! The code is pasted bellow:

Serial version:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#define M 100000000

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        drand48(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Parallel version:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#define M 100000000
#define N 4

pthread_t threads[N];

void* f(void* p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M/N; ++i)
        drand48();
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I executed both codes. The serial one runs in ~0.6 seconds and the parallel in ~2.1 seconds.

Could anyone explain me why this happens?

---

Some additional information: I have 4 cores on my PC. I compile the serial version using

> g++ serial.cpp -o serial

and the parallel using

> g++ parallel.cpp -lpthread -o parallel

---

Edit:

Apparently, this performance loss happens whenever I updates a global variable in my threads. In the exemple below, the x variable is the global (note that in the parallel example, the operation will be non thread-safe):

Serial:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#define M 1000000000

int x = 0;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        x = x + 10 - 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Parallel:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#define M 1000000000
#define N 4

pthread_t threads[N];
int x;

void* f(void* p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M/N; ++i)
        x = x + 10 - 10;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the drand48() uses the global struct variable **_libc_drand48_data**.

Comment: There is a big overhead to thread creation, the improvement due to parallelism has to be large enough to warrant the overhead.  For `M= 100000000` you've just discovered `M` is too small (or thread creation too slow).

Comment: That is not the case. If I change the function drand48() to a simple arithmethic function, the parallel program runs faster than the serial one.

Comment: Aha... then it is possible that drand48() is doing false sharing... that is when two threads share a cache line although the data they access isn't at the same address, and at least one of the threads is a writer - the cache line ping-pongs back-and-forth between the cores.. if there is high contention for the cache line performance suffers (sometimes dramatically).

Comment: That makes sense. But, how can I actually prove that the false sharing is really happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drand48()` uses the global struct variable `_libc_drand48_data`, it keeps state there (writes to it), and is therefore the source of cache line contention, which is very likely the source of the performance degradation.  It isn't `false sharing` as I initially suspected and wrote in the comments, it is *bona fide* sharing.  The reason there is no locking in the implementation of drand48() is two fold:

1. drand48() is [not required to be thread-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) "The drand48(), lrand48(), and mrand48() functions need not be thread-safe."
2. If two threads happen to access it at the same time, and their writes to memory are interleaved there is no harm done - the data structure is not corrupted, and it is, after all, supposed to return pseudo random data.

There are some subtle considerations (race conditions) in the use of drand48() when one thread is initializing state, [but considered harmless](http://www.evanjones.ca/random-thread-safe.html)

Notice below in __drand48_iterate how it stores to three 16-bit words in the global variable, this is where the random generator keeps its state, and this is the source of the cache-line contention between your threads

```
xsubi[0] = result & 0xffff;
xsubi[1] = (result >> 16) & 0xffff;
xsubi[2] = (result >> 32) & 0xffff;
```

### Source code

You provided the link to [drand48() source code](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/uclibc/0.9.27/drand48_8c.html#af9329f9acef07ca14ea2256191c3ce74) which I've included below for reference.  The problem is cache line contention when the state is updated

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Global state for non-reentrant functions.  Defined in drand48-iter.c.  */

extern struct drand48_data __libc_drand48_data;

double drand48(void)    
{
    double result;
    erand48_r (__libc_drand48_data.__x, &__libc_drand48_data, &result);
    return result;
}
```

And here is the source for `erand48_r`

```
extern int __drand48_iterate(unsigned short xsubi[3], struct drand48_data *buffer);

int erand48_r (xsubi, buffer, result)
      unsigned short int xsubi[3];
      struct drand48_data *buffer;
      double *result;
{
    union ieee754_double temp;

    /* Compute next state.  */
    if (__drand48_iterate (xsubi, buffer) < 0)
        return -1;

    /* Construct a positive double with the 48 random bits distributed over
       its fractional part so the resulting FP number is [0.0,1.0).  */

    temp.ieee.negative = 0;
    temp.ieee.exponent = IEEE754_DOUBLE_BIAS;
    temp.ieee.mantissa0 = (xsubi[2] << 4) | (xsubi[1] >> 12);
    temp.ieee.mantissa1 = ((xsubi[1] & 0xfff) << 20) | (xsubi[0] << 4);

    /* Please note the lower 4 bits of mantissa1 are always 0.  */
    *result = temp.d - 1.0;

    return 0;
}
```

And the implementation of `__drand48_iterate` which is where it writes back to the global

```
int
__drand48_iterate (unsigned short int xsubi[3], struct drand48_data *buffer)
{
    uint64_t X;
    uint64_t result;

    /* Initialize buffer, if not yet done.  */
    if (unlikely(!buffer->__init))
    {
        buffer->__a = 0x5deece66dull;
        buffer->__c = 0xb;
        buffer->__init = 1;
    }

    /* Do the real work.  We choose a data type which contains at least
       48 bits.  Because we compute the modulus it does not care how
       many bits really are computed.  */

    X = (uint64_t) xsubi[2] << 32 | (uint32_t) xsubi[1] << 16 | xsubi[0];

    result = X * buffer->__a + buffer->__c;

    xsubi[0] = result & 0xffff;
    xsubi[1] = (result >> 16) & 0xffff;
    xsubi[2] = (result >> 32) & 0xffff;

    return 0;
}
```